# Python3: option parser, check if a boolean option has been set

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

I want to a true/false option (-w) to my program.
If the option is set, I will be sorting the output.

I have the following option added:

```
parser.add_option("-w", "--without-replacement",
                  action="store_true", dest="replacement", default=False,
                  help="outpt lines without replacement")

replacement = options.replacement

if replacement
    if self.lines:
        self.lines.sort()
        last = self.lines[-1]
        for i in range(len(self.lines)-2, -1, -1):
            if last == self.lines[i]: del self.lines[i]
            else: last=self.lines[i]
```

When I run the program, I get following error:

```
  File "randline.py", line 65
    if replacement
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Can you help me figure out the correct syntax? Is the parser.add_option programmed correctly?

Comment: What are you trying to do in the iteration?

Answer (score 4):

The syntax error is because you forgot the colon after 'if replacement'.

You have to actually invoke the parser before the options will be available:

```
options = parser.parse_args()
```

If you are trying to remove duplicates in the for loop at the end, try this:

```
if replacement and self.lines:
    self.lines = list(set(self.lines))
    self.lines.sort()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if replacement
```

needs to be:

```
if replacement:
```

note the colon (`:`)